# How to use Cursor's in non Activity Classes

Tags: android, calllog, android-cursor

I wan't to get data's from `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI` in non Activity classes. Am using cursor to get these data's from CallLog. But in non activity class cursor shows some error so how i can how i can do this?

Presently am doing like this,

```
public class CallReceiver extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);     
    Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
 startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: if i remove extends Activity word i get, The method managedQuery(Uri, null, null, null, null) is undefined for the type CallReceiver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        ...
    }
    c.close();
```